# What is the event that gets fired when you click on a datagrid column to sort it?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

What is the event that gets fired when you click on a datagrid column to sort it? I could use that to know which column is getting sorted and hence have a common sortcomparefunction for all columns.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **headerRelease**:
>   Dispatched after the user clicks a
>   header cell.

[adobe docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/controls/DataGrid.html#event%3aheaderRelease)

Answer (score 0):

actually no event is fired at that time but a function is called named

```
sortCompareFunction
```

that compare the all items according to their data types like Number, Date etc.